# MS Access 2003/2007 - Chart Object on a sub form, not loading when parent forms load

Tags: ms-access, forms, ms-access-2007, subform

SO I have a subform, that simply has one chart object on it. Its small, and this is the only purpose of this sub. Then I have about 10 forms that each have a sub windows with this form as it's child. I use a UNION query to show the current balance of 10 accounts on each form with this chart for comparative purposes. Everything works fine except for one small thing...

when you open any of these forms, you have to take your mouse over to the actual sub window and click inside of it to get the chart to show. once you do it works fine, on any and all forms, but this same issue if recurring on all these forms as well, so I am sure I am missing something here??

Any ideas about this one?

thanks
Justin

Comment: Just guessing, have you tried Repaint of the sub in the form Load event?

Comment: Not sure if Repaint will do anything -- Refresh might. Or the graph object may need to be requeried (I don't know if it has a Requery method, as I gave up on MS Graph more than 10 years ago!).

Comment: yeah i tried me.Chart.requery (chart being the name of the OLE object). didn't work. its funnny...if you click the sub-window-area, then click something else, it will appear in every instance. so i tried to set focus on, and then off the object...but in the parent form. so i don't know exactly what to use to get to the .chart.setfocus, because that control is actually on the subform. I tried forms!subform.chart...can't do that. i tried me!subform.chart.setfocus, and that doesn't work either.....was just taking stabs basically.

Comment: @Remou...could you please provide an example of repainting if Form = frmMain, sub = frmSub, and Object = Chart? Thanks!

Comment: Does it have an Activate event/method? Perhaps setting focus to it?

Comment: nope it doesn't David....so let me ask you this...if it was a sub form that just contained a control like a text box, how would i reference it in the parent form's code-behind-form??
me.SubWindow.  only gets me the reference to the window and not what is inside it right? if i tried me.SubWindow.SubTextBox...it throws me an error. How do I reference controls in the subform? thanks guys!

Comment: A subform control is not a form, but a subform control has a Form property that returns a reference to the form loaded in the subform control, thus: Me!MySubForm.Form, where "MySubForm" is the name of the subform control (which be embedding a subform called "zzzzzSleepyForm" -- the subform control's name and existence is completely independent of the name of the subform embedded in it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can work this out by *not* using a subform, but rather a chart control directly inserted in the form. I know it can be a headache to design a chart control in every form, but by doing it, you can control directly the data source of the chart independently from any other form.

**Example:**

I will suppose that you need to update the chart after updating a text box (txtExample).
You can alter the data source of the control usint the `afterUpdate` event:

```
Private Sub txtExample_AfterUpdate()
  chart1.RowSource = "SELECT ... FROM ..." 
  chart1.Requery
End Sub
```

The `RowSource` property of the chart object will be altered and updated every time the value of the text box is updated.

Hope this works for you

Comment: Which version of MS-Graph is it that allows dynamic assignment of the SQL? I haven't mucked about with MS-Graph for well over 10 years, but one of the issues with it was that it wasn't easy to change the SQL at runtime so that you often had to edit a saved QueryDef in order to change the data the chart was based on. But, of course -- I could be misremembering, or newer versions of MS-Graph allow more flexibility.

Comment: @David...well I am not sure about all versions that allow it, but I know you can with 2003, and probably 2007 as well. I have a bunch of reports with charts that use the above method (sort of) values from a form are passed to the rowsource and when the reports are opened. I was just hoping that I could get it done differently with this because it is essentially the exact same chart on all these forms so I made a sub form with a chart to save myself some effort. but given that it is only about 10 forms, I guess I can go this route. I use the .rowsource method above on those reports though...

Answer (score 1):

I have looked around for this problem and found that `me.graph1.requery` doesn't help in my 2003 version. I did try in desperation this: `docmd.requery (Graph1)` that crashes but when you put `on error resume next` it does show the graph everytime! True Microsoft style I guess to fix it with another buggy thing.